# Dynamic Alert Service Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am using a dynamic Angular Alert service. Is there a way to style the text so that some words are bold and add new lines and center other parts. I would like success to bold and centered and the rest on the next line I tried adding `'\n'` , `'\b'` `<strong>` etc but it doesn't seem to work. I want to avoid manually typing it in the global service.:

```
this.alertService.success( "Success! you have successfully submitted your request")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use 
 instead of /n also remember the text must be added as x.innerhtml so something like this

```
    whateverfunction( "<strong>Success!</strong><br> you have successfully submitted your request")
function whateverfunction(text){
//other code
x.innerhtml = text
}
```

this should help

Comment: is that two separate functions?

Comment: no The fist one just calls it the other one is the function code

Comment: oh ok is there a way to add styling like `("<strong style: font-size:14px>Success!<strong>`